# Adjusting the Torso setting for the backpack

Tags: trekking, backpacks

I have been using backpacks which did not have setting for Torso adjustment. This time around I have bought myself a backpack with such adjustment.

[image]

Product Link: [Quechua backpack Product](http://www.quechua.com/en-IN/five-stars/88/symbium-access-backpack.html)

I think I still have not managed to adjust it neatly, as I found myself adjusting the straps all the time, and still ended up with an uneasy feeling with lower back and shoulders.

Are there any tips for how to adjust the torso setting?

Comment: when you say adjusting the straps, do you mean the back length straps or other ones?

Comment: @Liam: The other ones like the ones with shoulder straps and seldom I cared to adjust the back length. But yeah, nearly 5-6 times I adjusted the back length straps, and it didn't help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Back length

The first one to get right is the back length; loosen everything off (so you can wear it but nothing is tight) and put the pack on and see how it sits. You want the waist straps to sit just above your hips. If they don't adjust the back length (up or down). Once this is set **don't alter it**.

The other straps will likely alter depending on your clothing and what your carrying.

### Shoulder strap length/Chest strap

I'd put it on attach the chest strap and pull this into position, then  tighten the shoulder straps so that they're tight(ish). Then tighten the chest strap, you want the shoulder straps slightly off your shoulders so that some of the weight is distributed onto your chest slightly, this prevents heavy weight's pulling your shoulders too far back. The weight should be evenly distributed into a **H** shape across your chest and shoulders with no one part (one shoulder or just your chest or just your shoulders) holding more weight than the other areas. This evenly distributes the weight.

You shouldn't feel pulled into any particular position, if you are they're probably too tight.

### Shoulder length

The last strap to adjust is the shoulder length (the strap behind your shoulder). This is designed to slightly pull your shoulders back and evenly distribute the weight across your back (i.e. so that the weight doesn't simply sit on your lower back). Pull these tight so that you feel the weight move up slightly (to the middle of your back) and doesn't sit too low. You should feel your shoulders being *slightly* pulled straight and backwards (imagine your shoulder blades being pulled flat with your back, this should naturally adjust your posture so your shoulders are flatand your back straight).

### Waist strap

The back length dictates this really. You can alter the tightness but that's it really. It should be snug but not tight. Waist straps can distribute some of the weight from your lower back to your hip area. they also prevent the bottom of the bag from moving around

---

You will likely adjust the shoulder (not length) and chest strap often, but if you get the others right these shouldn't need to much adjustment at all. Adding and removing clothes alters your bulk so you will normally need to adjust your pack too. Adding and removing weight will also naturally require some adjustment. Try not to fiddle too much though, get it into a good position initially and try and maintain this position.

Comment: Nice answer. But what about the waist strap?

Comment: good point @nivag. I was thinking about my bag. I don't like waist straps. They get in the way when the going get's tough!

Comment: @Liam: I rather disagree, I rely a lot on waist straps and chest straps

Comment: I'm leaning too much towards my personal preference there I suppose, I've edited. @WedaPashi

Comment: @liam: Much appreciated!

Comment: @Liam: Normally, for heavier packs (~18kg and above), more than 50% of the weight should be on your waist, not on your shoulders. In smaller packs you might do without them, but for this type of backpack a waist strap definitely doesn´t get in the way, but is essential.